# Is there any way to concatenate macro arguments when condition is true?

Tags: c++, c

I want to concatenate the macro arguments when condition is true :

```
#define concat(x, y) (x##y)
#define concat_if(cond, x, y) (((cond) > 0) ? concat(x, y) : (x))
```

For example,

```
int concat_if(1, hello, 0);    //int hello0;
int concat_if(0, hello, 1);    //int hello;
```

But this will make compile-error (Clang) :

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'hello0'
    int concat_if(1, hello, 0);
        ^ note: expanded from macro 'concat_if'
#define concat_if(cond, x, y) (((cond) > 0) ? concat(x, y) : (x))
                                              ^ note: expanded from macro 'concat'
#define concat(x, y) (x##y)
                      ^
<scratch space>:303:1: note: expanded from here
hello0
^
error: use of undeclared identifier 'hello'
    int concat_if(1, hello, 0);
                     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[With Boost.PP](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/728260ca72aba96a):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define concat_if(cond, x, y) BOOST_PP_IF(cond, BOOST_PP_CAT(x, y), (x))

int concat_if(1, hello, 0);    //int hello0;
int concat_if(0, hello, 1);    //int (hello);
```

[From scratch](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24d907a35ef338f8), it's easy to emulate what Boost does:

```
#define concat(x, y) concat_i(x, y)
#define concat_i(x, y) x##y

#define concat_if(cond, x, y) concat(concat_if_, cond)(x, y)
#define concat_if_0(x, y) (x)
#define concat_if_1(x, y) concat(x, y)

int concat_if(1, hello, 0);    //int hello0;
int concat_if(0, hello, 1);    //int (hello);
```

The condition is appended to a helper macro prefix and separate macros are defined for either result. Note that I'd recommend making all of these macros FULL_UPPERCASE.

Comment: I had this in mind too, but I don't see a way to do it with an actual conditional on a value rather than specific value tokens.

Comment: @R.., Absolutely, the condition must be known at PP time.

Comment: Congratulations.  The only problem I see is that you have to have hard-wired `0` or `1` as the condition — you can't have an arbitrary expression as the condition.  And with hard-wired conditions, the macro ceases to have much meaning.  That's not your fault; it's just a comment on the conditions set up by the question.  I don't think there is a good motivation from the OP for doing this — it's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) as already said [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623996/15168).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes, it lacks a lot of flexibility, but it also has a considerable amount of flexibility given that you can do PP-time transformations to end up at the 0 or 1 and have it still work. I imagine most of the use cases for these macros involve configuration constants, and those use cases are generally pretty workable. I would certainly be interested in the need for this macro and example use specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just pre-process

```
int main()
{
   int concat_if(1, hello, 0);    //int hello0;
   int concat_if(0, hello, 1);    //int hello;
}
```

you get

```
int main()
{
   int (((1) > 0) ? (hello0) : (hello));
   int (((0) > 0) ? (hello1) : (hello));
}
```

As you can see, the compiler has to process all those tokens. Those lines are syntactically invalid since the conditional expressions are, well, expressions. The need to be evaluatable.

In other words, using the conditional operator to declare variables of different names is not a viable strategy.

I am not able to suggest anything to solve your problem since I don't understand what the  real problem is. It feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at the moment.